# How do we get iOS 15.1 simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios15

For our projects we need to be get our build and release infrastructure with latest Xcode and iOS releases.
Apple has released Xcode 13.1 and iOS 15.1 on last week of October 2021, but there are no iOS 15.1 targets(simulators) for running tests against.

Any idea on when do they normally show up in the Xcode?

Comment: If this helps, I'm using Xcode 13.1 and am *unable* to target iOS 15.1 - period. Just 15.0. I'd expect that the simulators follow course with this. IMHO iOS/iPadOS 15.1, Xcode 13.1, and macOS 12.0.1 were *all* released last Monday and likely the main "target" was the macOS release, which was timed to work with the new M1 Pro/Max MacBook Pros. They released macOS 12.0.1 (and maybe iPadOS 15.1 too) because of the "rollback" of Safari 15 to have a **much** more normal UI.

Comment: Thanks @dfd, but is this the normal release flow? Any info on how soon would iOS 15.1 targets be released? Checked some timelines wiki here https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Timeline but nothing mentioned on how apple used to do previously?

Comment: Try the new beta iOS 15.2

Comment: Why the concern? Seriously, 15.0.2 - that used 15.0 - isn't a big deal different than 15.1. Is there something that makes you need a 15.1 simulator? If so, then how about an actual device running 15.1? I have four. Surely you can find one. Apple does, well, what it does. There is little rhyme or reason. With all due respect, **last week** they already released beta versions or 15.2! Please, why are you looking for a 15.1 simulator?

Comment: For our projects, we need to upgrade our infrastructure along with the releases from apple. As part of it, we wanted to 
- upgrade our build machines with latest xcode 13.1 
- run all our tests against the latest iOS release (15.1)

Comment: Looks like apple doesn't have iOS 15.1 simulator support. I have installed Xcode 13.2 beta and it has support for iOS 15.2/ iOS 15.0 and other iOS 14 but not iOS 15.1 simulators.